# AS3 Class inheritance problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Please help Stackoverflow! I have a MapInterface class in AS3 that inherits from Interface class.

```
public class Interface extends Sprite {
    public function Interface(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and then

```
import com.georgecrabtree.Interface;

public class MapInterface extends Interface {
    public function MapInterface(){
        addMapButtons();
    }
    public function addMapButtons():void {
        trace("init");
    }
}
```

this all works fine, and when I create a new MapInterface class from the document class it traces out init. But when I try to call this:

```
var mapInterface:MapInterface = new MapInterface();
mapInterface.addMapButtons();
```

from the main timeline I get this error:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addMapButtons through a reference with static type com.georgecrabtree:Interface.
```

Thanks in advance for any help, George

Comment: naming your class interface seems like a very risky thing to do, interface (with a lowercase i) is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think your second code sample has a typo. I imagine it is actually:

```
var mapInterface:Interface = new MapInterface();
mapInterface.addMapButtons();
```

The problem is that your variable is of type `Interface`, which does not define an `addMapButtons()` method. You can fix the problem either by changing the variable type to MapInterface, or by adding an `addMapButtons()` method to Interface and overriding the method in MapInterface.

Comment: Thanks for your help Richard, but surely if the MapInterface class extends the Interface class and then I create the mapInterface var as an MapInterface, it should be of type MapInterface? Also if I trace the variable trace(mapInterface) just before the addMapButtons(); function call it the output window shows that it is  of type MapInterface?!

Comment: Your original code looks like it should compile to me. If a variable is typed as a superclass, the child class properties are not available (unless you cast the variable to the child class type).

Comment: Still waiting for confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for your help and attention on this one. After a good nights sleep I finally figured out my problem. Obviously the code I posted above was a watered down version of what I actually had.

The problem was that my document class was not extending Sprite, it was extending a class called Installation which itself extends Sprite. This was because I am making 10 installations and they all have a a bunch of common ground, they all have a screen saver, intro video, etc. They all have an interface too, which is where my problem came in, as 9 of the installations use the same interface, but one (the map installation) needed to have a few extra GUI elements.

My problem was that my Installation base class looked like this (im showing a trimmed down version):

```
public class Installation extends Sprite {

    protected var _interface:Interface;

    public function Installation(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

So when my MapInstallation extended this class it inherited the _interface variable. So when I created the _interface variable as type MapInterface..

```
_interface = new MapInterface();
```

..the complier recognised the new MapInterface as of type Installation but the _interface variable was still strongly typed as Interface, so when I later tried to call the addMapButtons() function on _interface, although the function was there the complier had other ideas. My solution was to using casting..

```
(_interface as MapInterface).addMapButtons();
```

and it all worked hunky dory. Thanks for your help guys :)